# How do you unlock bootloader

Tags: bootloader-lock

How do you unlock the bootloader of the huawei y5ii because I would like to flash TWRP

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need an unlock code from Huawei from them [here](https://emui.huawei.com/en/plugin/unlock/index), then unlock the bootloader with the code they provide using the fastboot command `fastboot oem unlock XXXX`, where XXXX is the code they provided.

Then using fastboot and the TWRP recovery for your device, flash it using:  `fastboot flash recovery nameofTWRPfile.img`

That is the basics taken from XDA [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/root-huawei-y5-ii-cun-l21-l03-t3536329).